# Build an editor with uploadable images anywhere inside text

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce, paperclip

I know how to build a form to upload images with gem `paperclip`

And integrate gem `tinymce` to write a rich text article

What if to build an Rich text editor, so that I can put text anywhere and insert image anywhere in a WYSIWYG way ?

What's the common way to finish it with Rails

Answer (score 0):

There are gems, libraries available to do exactly that. 
Here are some https://github.com/volmer/bootsy and https://rubygems.org/gems/ckeditor-rails

Among the client side libraries, you could use http://ckeditor.com/

There is no common way since it all depends on the requirements and mostly to the developers choice and comfort.